# Getting iPhone carrier without CoreTelephony

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-telephony, carrier

Is there any way to get phone's carrier without using CoreTelephony framework? (1.2Mb is too big for my case for just getting the carrier)

Answer (score 1):

Using CoreTelephony framework shouldn't increase your file-size that much, as CoreTelephony framework is provided by the OS, it wont get compiled into your app.

If you compile [CoreTelephonyDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTelephonyDemo/Introduction/Intro.html), the app size is about 60KB.

Comment: In some cases, I would like to compile that code into a library. Is it possible to encapsulate the CoreTelephony in that?

Comment: you can write any kind of library, that uses that framework. and as it is available for all iOS devices, there is no need to compile it into you library.

Comment: the thing is that i do not want the framework to be imported from the application side. I just need to drag and drop that library without any prerequisites. will this be possible?

Comment: so you dont want to have an app, that is 1.2MB big, but you want to duplicate existing frameworks? and no, I dont think, that is possible. While it might be possible technically, I assume apple wont like the idea of you duplicating and re-distributing their frameworks.

Comment: sorry if got misunderstood, I don't want to re-distribute apple's framework, I just need the information about the carrier, without having to insert the framework every time in my apps. So, going back to my initial question, is it possible to read that info WITHOUT the CoreTelephony? Maybe with some c/cpp code?

Comment: listen, what do u do to insert the framework? becuase it shouldnt be a hassle. you just need to link against it. Are you copying it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21271/discussion-between-vame-and-vikingosegundo)

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase is to just retrieve iPhone's carrier information, do use [CoreTelephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) framework as it is provided by Apple. It won't increase your app size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please see my comment in the answer below.